# How to extract rows of a dataframe which match with an occurence?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with 3 columns, which looks like this :

```
       var1    var2   corr
1   OTU0001 OTU0004  0.882
2   OTU0001 OTU0014  0.656
3   OTU0004 OTU0014  0.456
4   OTU0001 OTU0015  0.690
5   OTU0004 OTU0015  0.612
6   OTU0014 OTU0015  0.565
7   OTU0001 OTU0016  0.652
8   OTU0004 OTU0016  0.630
9   OTU0014 OTU0016  0.465
10  OTU0015 OTU0016  0.884
11  OTU0001 OTU0017  0.766
```

I would like to extract the rows who match with the occurence "OTU0016" for example. I should get

```
7   OTU0001 OTU0016  0.652
8   OTU0004 OTU0016  0.630
9   OTU0014 OTU0016  0.465
10  OTU0015 OTU0016  0.884
```

I tried `grep("^OTU0016$",Df)` , but it only returns me `integer(0)`

Comment: Can it occur in any column? If only in `var2`, then you can use `Df[grep("^OTU0016$", Df$var2), ]` or `Df[grep("^OTU0016$", Df$var1) | grep("^OTU0016$", Df$var2), ]`

Comment: It can occurs in `var1` or `var2`, `corr` is only a column with number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 filter_at(vars(starts_with("var")), any_vars(. == "OTU0016"))

     var1    var2  corr
1 OTU0001 OTU0016 0.652
2 OTU0004 OTU0016 0.630
3 OTU0014 OTU0016 0.465
4 OTU0015 OTU0016 0.884
```

Or with `base R`:

```
df[apply(df[, 1:2], 1, function(x) any(grepl("OTU0016", x, fixed = TRUE))), ]

      var1    var2  corr
7  OTU0001 OTU0016 0.652
8  OTU0004 OTU0016 0.630
9  OTU0014 OTU0016 0.465
10 OTU0015 OTU0016 0.884
```

Or:

```
df[apply(df[, -grepl("corr", names(df), fixed = TRUE)], 1, function(x) any(grepl("OTU0016", x, fixed = TRUE))), ]
```

Or:

```
df[apply(df[, -grepl("corr", names(df), fixed = TRUE)], 1, function(x) any(match(x, "OTU0016", nomatch = 0))), ]
```

Comment: @tmfmnk - why using `rowMeans` instead of `rowSums`, I suppose it will be less efficient ? - It is a good practice to use `fixed = TRUE` in `grepl`. - And I don't think that using apply is necessary here, a bit overkill for a simple question

Answer (score 2):

For all columns you can use :

```
Df[rowSums(Df == "OTU0016") > 0,]
```

For your two columns :

```
Df[rowSums(Df[c("var1", "var2") == "OTU0016") > 0,]
```

Or

```
Df[Df$var1 == "OTU0016" | Df$var2 == "OTU0016",]
```